# como puedo comparar la fecha de un mes y dia

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

el programa tiene que calcular la diferencia de dias de una fecha, solo se requiere de el mes y dia
lo estaba elaborando, pero me compara el año igual

```js
 public String fecha(){
        String fecha1, fecha2, m = "pago retraso";
        System.out.println("ingrese la fecha registro  : mm-dd");
        fecha1=entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ingrese la fecha pago : mm-dd");
        fecha2=entrada.nextLine();
        
      LocalDate fecha1l=LocalDate.parse(fecha1, formatter);
      LocalDate fecha2l = LocalDate.parse(fecha2, formatter);
      if(fecha1l.isEqual(fecha2l)){
         m=("pago al dia");
          
      }
      if(fecha1l.isAfter(fecha2l)){
          
          
      }
        return m;
        
    }
```

Comment: una idea ,podes trabajar con las dos fechas obtenidas como tipo String. usar el metodo split("-") para obtener mes y dia por separado ,hacer un cast a tipo int y realizar la operacion de diferencia entre meses y dias de ambas fechas respectivamente

Comment: muchas gracias!!